# Adjusting Boostrap container's RIGHT margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

It took me several seconds to adjust left margin on Bootstrap container (narrowing the white blank space on the left side), but now I spent several hours googling to make the same adjustment on the right margin, and so success. Did anyone have idea how to fix it ?

Important note! Ideally, I would avoid editing the original Bootstrap file, and instead put some CSS over the the Bootstrap file. This simple code solved the left margin. I guess, I have to edit the WIDTH of the container, but no idea how to do this in a semantically correct way.

```
.container{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tceLzqmx/

Comment: It's all about asymmetry. The white space in the left corner is much narrower than the white space on the right side

Comment: If this is a permanent change, are you able to use the customizing tool ? (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) - that'd be my preferred choice

Comment: `container` has fixed pixel sizes dependent on screen resolution.  if you want it to stretch to the other end of the screen and have even margins regardless of size, you need to use `container-fluid` instead.

Comment: If you look at the provided asnwer below, this solves the issue if I add margin-left and equal margin-right (say, 100px). But I can also use Paul Abbott's solution and apply margin-right and margin-left to container-fluid. The only difference is that with container-fluid I don't have to set width:auto. I feel both solutions are semantically acceptable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `container-fluid` which doesn't have a fixed width. By default it has no margin so you can add it the same way you did for `container`, or make it a bit more compact:

```
.container-fluid {
    margin: auto 10px;
}
```

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r9ektzc/2/)

If you override all the width settings of the `container` element you cannot use it at it's original intent which is responsive width based on window size.

Answer (score 1):

You may set your container with width: auto

```css
.container{
  width: auto  
}
```

Comment: Yes, adding margin-left and margin-right solves this